# How are WCF Callback size limits configured?

Tags: wcf, callback, wcf-binding

In WCF you can configure the max size of the message through binding configurations (maxReceivedMessageSize, readerQuotas, etc)

Does that configuration apply to callback messages as well or is there another place where i can configure that?

Comment: Probably it gets parameters from client's app.config file. But I'm not sure, my callbacks are allways one-way.

Answer (score 0):

These settings apply to all incoming messages. Whether or not they are callback messages is irrelevant. Let me know if you are noticing conflicting behavior!